# Application icon is not displayed in Xamarin.Forms Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, icons

I cannot figure out why my Xamarin.Forms Android app has the default robot icon.

Here is the structure I have now:

[image]

And here is what I have in "MainActivity.cs":

```
[Activity(Label = "My App Name", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

And here is what I have in "AndroidManifest.xml":

```
<application android:label="My App Name" android:icon="@mipmap/icon"></application>
```

And in "icon.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/icon" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Some solutions that I found online suggest moving the icons to the "drawable" folder, but I am not sure those solutions are up to date. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Check that all the `icon.png` files in the different mipmap directories have the correct image. Also, if you open `icon.xml` file inside **mipmap-anydpi-v26** directory what does it look like?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and my code look exactly like yours. I will try to move the icon to the .Android/Resources/drawable folder and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**mipmap-anydpi-v26** means for SDK 26 or greater, it uses the files in the folder of the XML file to use adaptive icons.

If your device version is lower than 26, you could check if the `icon.png` is stored in the folders correctly. If the version greater than or equal to 26, you could check the `icon.xml`.

By the way, the easiest way is put your icon.png into `Resources/drawable` folder, then use like:

```
[Activity(Label = "My App Name", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you suggesting placing icon.png to each of the drawable folders, i.e. drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi, or just drawable? Why is it easier than just leaving them where they are? Also, if I move them to drawable(s), should I remove them from mipmaps?

Comment: yes,similar to mipmaps, it also loads images based on pixel density,by the way i want to say the mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before,this is also officially recommended,but now,i couldn't know why your icon not display,do you check your `icon.xml` and `icon.png` ? or try to rename them,if still not work,put the icon to drawable as a workaround.